# R Survminer Pairwise Survival difference Variable length error

Tags: r, survival

Hello I am using the `survival` package and the `survminer` package to do some analysis. I am having trouble with `pairwise_survdiff` from the `survminer` package.

Here is some simulated data that mimics my own.

```
set.seed(123)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
size <-  30
treatment <- c(rep(1, size),
               rep(2, size),
               rep(3, size))
deathtime <- c(rexp(size, rate = 1),
               rexp(size, rate = 2),
               rexp(size, rate = 3))
censor <- c(rbinom(size, 1, .1),
            rbinom(size, 1, .1),
            rbinom(size, 1, .1))


df <- data.frame(treatment, deathtime, censor)
```

Doing the survival analysis

```
surv.obj<- Surv(df$deathtime, abs(df$censor -1))

survdiff(surv.obj ~ treatment, data = df)
```

[image]

Now trying pairwise

```
pairwise_survdiff(surv.obj ~ treatment, data = df) # from survminer
```

[image]

```
length(df[,"treatment"]) == length(surv.obj)
```

[image]

I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without using the `df$`

```
pairwise_survdiff(Surv(deathtime, abs(censor -1)) ~ treatment, data = df)
```

-output

```
Pairwise comparisons using Log-Rank test 

data:  df and treatment 

  1      2     
2 0.1389 -     
3 0.0022 0.0364

P value adjustment method: BH
```